# ElasticPress is (aparently) messing with my search filters

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, query-posts, meta-query

I recently installed ElasticPress on my woocommerce store, and it's working fine -- the product page is showing normally, and the search bar is working fine with the new elastic capabilities. However, when I try to use the product filters, nothing shows up, the query simply doesn't work. If I deactivate Elasticpress, however, the filters work normally. This is the query:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $wp_query;

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'tpk_archive_query' );

function tpk_archive_query( $q ){

    if($_GET['js'] == 'y') {
        $cat = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['categorias']));
        $a = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['artistas']));
        $ta = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos']));
        $c = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['colecoes']));
        $t = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['tags']));
        $preco = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['preco']));
        $operador = strtoupper(esc_attr($_GET['op']));
        $orderby = explode('-', esc_attr($_GET['orderby']));
    } else {
        $cat = esc_attr($_GET['cat']);
        $a = esc_attr($_GET['a']);
        $ta = esc_attr($_GET['ta']);
        $c = esc_attr($_GET['c']);
        $t = esc_attr($_GET['t']);
    }



    if((esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['orderby'])))) {

        if($orderby[0] == 'preco') {

            $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $q->set('meta_key', '_price');
            $q->set('order', $orderby[1]);

        } else {

            $q->set('orderby', $orderby[0]);
            $q->set('order', $orderby[1]);

        }

    }



    $args = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ];

    if((esc_attr($_GET['cat']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['cat'])))) {
        
        $category = [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $cat,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $category);
    } elseif(esc_attr($_GET['categorias']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['categorias']))) {

        if(in_array('kits', $cat)) {

            $categorias = ['relation' => 'OR',];

            foreach ($cat as $cate) {

                if($cate != 'kits') {

                    $kitCat = 'kits-' . $cate;

                    $cate = [$cate, $kitCat];

                    $pima = [
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $cate,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    ];
                    
                    array_push($categorias, $pima);

                }

            }

        } else {

            $categorias = [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $cat,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ];

        }

        array_push($args, $categorias);

    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['a']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['a']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['artistas']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['artistas'])))) {
        $artistas = [
            'taxonomy' => 'autor',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $a,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $artistas);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['ta']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['ta']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos'])))) {
        $tamanho = [
            'taxonomy' => 'tamanho',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ta,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $tamanho);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['c']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['c']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['colecoes']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['colecoes'])))) {
        $colecao = [
            'taxonomy' => 'colecao',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $c,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $colecao);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['t']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['t']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['tags']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['tags'])))) {
        
        if(!$operador) {
            $operador = 'OR';
        }
        $tags = ['relation' => $operador,];

        foreach ($t as $tag) {
            $poma = [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $tag,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ];
            
            array_push($tags, $poma);
        }

        array_push($args, $tags);
    }

    $q->set('tax_query', $args);

    if((esc_attr($_GET['preco']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['preco'])))) {

        $min_price = $preco[0];
        $max_price = $preco[1];

        $q->set('meta_query', [
            [
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => [$min_price, $max_price],
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ]
        ]);

    }

}
```

I tried using WP Marvelous Debug to see if there were any errors happening during the query, and it didn't point at anything different. The only "errors" it pointed out were [these undefined indexes](https://i.ibb.co/dp3zhsR/image.png), which I don't belive have anything to do with the problem, because they happen with or without Elastic.

This is the "Query Args" on the ElasticPress debugger:

```
array(72) {
["orderby"]=>
string(28) "meta.total_sales.double date"
["post_type"]=>
string(7) "product"
["error"]=>
string(0) ""
["m"]=>
string(0) ""
["p"]=>
int(0)
["post_parent"]=>
string(0) ""
["subpost"]=>
string(0) ""
["subpost_id"]=>
string(0) ""
["attachment"]=>
string(0) ""
["attachment_id"]=>
int(0)
["name"]=>
string(0) ""
["pagename"]=>
string(0) ""
["page_id"]=>
int(0)
["second"]=>
string(0) ""
["minute"]=>
string(0) ""
["hour"]=>
string(0) ""
["day"]=>
int(0)
["monthnum"]=>
int(0)
["year"]=>
int(0)
["w"]=>
int(0)
["category_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["tag"]=>
string(0) ""
["cat"]=>
string(0) ""
["tag_id"]=>
string(0) ""
["author"]=>
string(0) ""
["author_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["feed"]=>
string(0) ""
["tb"]=>
string(0) ""
["paged"]=>
int(0)
["meta_key"]=>
string(0) ""
["meta_value"]=>
string(0) ""
["preview"]=>
string(0) ""
["s"]=>
string(0) ""
["sentence"]=>
string(0) ""
["title"]=>
string(0) ""
["fields"]=>
string(0) ""
["menu_order"]=>
string(0) ""
["embed"]=>
string(0) ""
["category__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["category__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["category__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_name__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag_slug__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag_slug__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_parent__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_parent__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["author__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["author__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["order"]=>
string(4) "DESC"
["meta_query"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tax_query"]=>
array(2) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(5) "autor"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "slug"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "arcane-minis"
    }
    ["operator"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    }
}
["wc_query"]=>
string(13) "product_query"
["posts_per_page"]=>
int(48)
["ep_integrate"]=>
bool(true)
["ep_facet"]=>
bool(true)
["aggs"]=>
array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "terms"
    ["use-filter"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["aggs"]=>
    array(12) {
    ["category"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(19) "terms.category.slug"
        }
    }
    ["post_tag"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(19) "terms.post_tag.slug"
        }
    }
    ["post_format"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(22) "terms.post_format.slug"
        }
    }
    ["product_cat"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(22) "terms.product_cat.slug"
        }
    }
    ["product_tag"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(22) "terms.product_tag.slug"
        }
    }
    ["product_shipping_class"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(33) "terms.product_shipping_class.slug"
        }
    }
    ["autor"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(16) "terms.autor.slug"
        }
    }
    ["colecao"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(18) "terms.colecao.slug"
        }
    }
    ["tamanho"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(18) "terms.tamanho.slug"
        }
    }
    ["ep_custom_result"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(27) "terms.ep_custom_result.slug"
        }
    }
    ["pa_material"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(22) "terms.pa_material.slug"
        }
    }
    ["pa_variacao"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["size"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["field"]=>
        string(22) "terms.pa_variacao.slug"
        }
    }
    }
}
["suppress_filters"]=>
bool(false)
["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
bool(false)
["cache_results"]=>
bool(true)
["update_post_term_cache"]=>
bool(true)
["lazy_load_term_meta"]=>
bool(true)
["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
bool(true)
["nopaging"]=>
bool(false)
["comments_per_page"]=>
string(2) "30"
["no_found_rows"]=>
bool(false)
["taxonomy"]=>
string(5) "autor"
["term"]=>
string(12) "arcane-minis"
}
```

Do I have to re-write my queries in an elastic-specific syntax? I spent the last two days trying to fix this and I really have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**---EDIT---**

In case this is helpful: this is the generated query without any filters active (just the default woocommerce query, which works without any problems):

```
{
"query": {
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

And this is the generated query when I set the "autor" filter as "Arcane Minis", and the "orderby" to "popularity":

```
{
"query": {
    "orderby": "",
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "0": {
        "taxonomy": "autor",
        "field": "slug",
        "terms": [
        "arcane-minis"
        ],
        "operator": "IN"
    },
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

And lastly, this is the filtered query without elastic press:

```
{
"query": {
    "orderby": "",
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "0": {
        "taxonomy": "autor",
        "field": "slug",
        "terms": [
        "arcane-minis"
        ],
        "operator": "IN"
    },
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

Comment: I know EP allows you to explicitly define that it should be used in a query, check if they have a similar parameter that allows you to explicitly tell it to NOT become involved.

Comment: @TonyDjukic That's pretty interesting, thanks! It's definetly not the ideal solution, since I want elastic's capabilities on these queries, but if I can't find any other solution, that would probably be a nice compromise.

Comment: :facepalm:  Didn't even occur to me that you WANT ElasticPress still involved.  Sorry.

Comment: @TonyDjukic As I said, that's a nice compromise, in case I can't find another solution. I tried adding `$q->set('ep_integrate', false);` to my query, but when I check it with the query monitor, it says ep_integrate is set to 1. It seems elasticpress is happening after my query. Is there anyway I can increase my query's priority, like an `!important` in CSS?

Comment: Acutally, I'm just kinda dumb. I had the `$q->set('ep_integrate', false);` under the wrong conditional. So yeah, in case I can't solve this problem, I'll just turn off EP on this query.